# Is the special attack granted by Righteous Might a Strike?

Tags: spells, attack, pathfinder-2e

Casting [Righteous Might](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=263) gives the caster a *special attack*:

> A *special attack* with a righteous armament version of your favored weapon, which is the only attack you can use. Your attack modifier with the special weapon is +21, and your damage bonus is +8 (or +6 for a ranged attack). If your attack modifier with your deity's favored weapon is higher, you can use it instead. You deal three of your weapon's normal damage dice, or three damage dice of one size larger if your weapon is a simple weapon with a d4 or d6 damage die. The weapon has one of the following properties that matches your deity's alignment: anarchic, axiomatic, holy, unholy. If your deity is true neutral, you instead deal an extra 1d6 precision damage.

The [Attack Roll](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=321) rules seem to make a difference between Strikes and *special attacks*:

> The multiple attack penalty (detailed on page 446) applies to each attack after the first, whether those attacks are Strikes, *special attacks* like the Grapple action of the Athletics skill, or spell attack rolls.

It not being a Strike would seem to imply that:

- You can't use it with [Power Attack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=359)
- It does not deal double damage on a [critical hit](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=222)

**Is the special attack granted by Righteous Might a Strike?**

Comment: We generally prefer a single focused question per post, 11 questions is way too much. Is there a particular aspect of the spell that is confusing you, that if clarified, would help answer these 11 questions on your own?

Comment: As Thomas has said, try and limit the post to one question. For example, half of these seem to be asking about what can affect the special attack. You can ask separate questions for the "favored weapon", and perhaps attack/damage modifiers.

Comment: What might help us to answer, is to [edit] this down to one question, as others have suggested. If an answer already exists in some form on the site, we will add a notice to the post that points you (and any future answerer) that way. Otherwise it'll get answered here. After that feel free to ask the next question from your list, and so on ...

Comment: A portion of this question (3&4 at least) is answered [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/180648/31647).

Comment: Edited to reduce scope.

Answer (score 7):

### It's an attack with a weapon, so you can use a Strike action.

Righteous Might has particularly confusing wording with its attack. Of the battle form spells I looked at, it's the only one that includes "special." Spells like [Animal Form](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=10) and [Dragon Form](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=88) specify an unarmed attack, while [Avatar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=16) unhelpfully says "one or more attacks" with no further specificity.

Especially with regards to battle forms, the words attack and Strike are often used interchangeably. The [polymorph](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=127) trait rules refer to these as "Strikes granted by a polymorph effect" when specifying that they are magical, which I think is the clearest indicator of how to handle these attacks.

Looking at Righteous Might's rules text specifically, what's special about the attack appears to be that it is made with a version of your deity's favored weapon. Unlike the typical unarmed attacks of battle forms, as a weapon, it has its regular weapon traits on top of the benefits of Righteous Might. Otherwise, I'm not sure why the word "special" is in the text.

### TL;DR, and to answer the specific questions:

Yes, you would use the Strike action for this attack, so its damage would be doubled on a critical success. You can use Power Attack or any other feat that involves making a Strike while in this form as long as they meet the restrictions of the Polymorph trait.

Comment: "since no battle forms I found had text about Strikes--they used "attack" instead"
I think this is a bit misleading. Sure, neither Animal Form nor Dragon Form use the word Strike, but they use the "Melee"-syntax described in the bestiary. The rules for that syntax explicitly states that those are "for a melee Strike".

I do personally think it is supposed to be a Strike RAI, but find RAW for Righteous Might very vague compared to other similar spells.

Comment: I think the only misleading word is "special" and it's not really a "defined" game term (yes, grapple and trip are *described* as "special attacks" but that's not a category of attacks). Otherwise, I think Attack and Strike are intended to be interchangable except in the context of a "spell attack" which is a defined term

Comment: I agree that the terms "attack" and "Strike" being interchangeable in this context is closer to the right answer, so I will edit my response accordingly. I think a couple years of 5e's distinguishing between "a melee weapon attack" and "the Attack action" made me overthink this a bit.